# mysql joining 2 tables getting 2 different values from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables that I would like to join...

Table "users":

Columns:

uid => user index

name => user name

---

Table "messages":

Columns:

fromid => sender user index

toid => receiver user index

message => text message

---

I want an output like this:
| from_username | to_username | message |

I can get | from_username | message |
with this query:

```
SELECT messages.message, users.name FROM messages,users WHERE messages.fromid = users.uid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to complete the join twice:

```
Select f.name, t.name, message from messages
Left join users as f on messages.fromID = f.uid
Left join users as t On messages.toid = t.uid
```

For the complete join syntax (and some explanation) the MySQL doc page is not bad http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Left join users as f where messages.fromID = f.uid , Left join ' at line 2

Comment: You are correct I have edited the answer, so syntax is "join table name on" not where.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 SELECT sender.name, receiver.name, message
 FROM messages
 INNER JOIN users sender
 ON messages.fromid = sender.uid
 INNER JOIN users receiver
 ON messages.toid = receiver.uid
```

Comment: Doesn't work propely, but thank you! I already have my answer!